# erro 500 no servidor

Tags: php, htaccess, servidor

Os erros encontrados foram:

```
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
getdate(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.
Undefined variable: resultadoVer
Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
Notice: Undefined index: Key
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
Warning: date(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.
```

Em relação ao código fonte, estamos usando POO:

```
include("inc/Conecta.class.php");
include("inc/Metodos.class.php");
$metodos = new Metodos();
```

Fazemos a conexao:

```
class Conecta{

      private $Servidor = 'XXX';
      private $Usuario = 'XXX';
      private $Senha = 'XXX';
      private $Banco = 'XXX';


        protected $Conecta;
        protected $Teste;

     public function conectar(){   


       $this->Conecta = mysqli_connect($this->Servidor,$this->Usuario,$this->Senha,$this->Banco) or die("Erro 001: Erro ao conectar no servidor");

       if ($this->Conecta == false) {
          printf("Erro ao conectar: %s\n", mysqli_connect_errnor());
          $this->erro(mysqli_connect_errnor());
          exit();
       }

       mysqli_set_charset($this->Conecta, "utf8");   

      }

      public function erro($erro_valor){
             error_log(filter_input(INPUT_SERVER,"PHP_SELF")." - Erro: 01 (".@date("d/m/Y") ." as ".@date("H:i").") - ".$erro_valor."\r\n",3,"log/erro.log");
      }

     public function fechar(){
         mysqli_close($this->Conecta);      
    }
 }
```

E o Metodos.class.php tem quase 2000 linhas, ficaria muita coisa. Então estamos fazendo dessa forma:

```
      class Metodos extends Conecta{

    ***// As linhas seguem abaixo***  

// Erro:  getdate(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.
$hoje = getdate();

// Erro:  Undefined variable: resultadoVer
$resultadoVer .= "<div class=\"list-group\">"; 

// Erro:  Undefined property: stdClass::$IdCodUsuarios
public function usuariosOnline($idUsuarios) {
        $resultados = "<a href='enviar.php?Key=".$jmVerPerfil->IdCodUsuarios."'";
return $resultados;
}

// Erro: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

public function cadastrarVisitas($id,$idVisitado){

          $conectar = new Conecta(); 
          $conectar->conectar();
$sqlVerificar = mysqli_query($conectar->Conecta, "SELECT * FROM verificar WHERE IdVisitantes = ".$id." AND IdVisitado = ".$jmVisitado->IdUsuarios."");
......
}
```

A versão do PHP do servidor atual é PHP: 5.5.23. Do servidor antigo não me lembro.

Comment: Erro 500 é de programação, habilte as mensagens de erro no host de produção, veja no wiki da tag php o item tela em branco.

Comment: Perdao rray, não consegui entendê-lo..

Comment: Geralmente é por causa da versão do php ou mod_rewrite desabilitado ou seu arquivo .htaccess tá com o encoding de BOM.

Comment: Adicione essas duas linha no primeiro arquivo que é carregado:
`ini_set('display_errors', true); error_reporting(E_ALL);` depois edite a resposta coloque a mensagem do erro e o código fonte. Qual é versão do php do host antigo e do atual?

Comment: Oi Leandro... na verdade nao estamos usando .htaccess.

Comment: Certo rray, estarei incluindo as linhas e postando aqui o erro.

Comment: Alterei a resposta com os erros e o código

Comment: Coloque as linhas onde são indicados os erros, não precisa ser o código todo.

Comment: Olá rray. Coloquei os erros encontrados e as linhas...

Comment: Diferente do título da pergunta, os dados que você passou como erros não são erros, efetuando uma leitura básica são Notices e Warning os quais não geram erro 500 seria interessante ter mais informações ou até mesmo você poderia dar uma olhada no log do apache para obter o real problema.

Comment: Certo Otto... após colocar o código que o rray informou, só aparecem avisos.. isso quer dizer que pode ser do próprio servidor? Estamos em uma hospedagem Linux...

Comment: através da minha busca, vi que pode ser configurações do PHP memory_limit. Para alterar no código, teria que colocar ini_set("memory_limit","256M"); certo?

Comment: Conseguiu resolver seu problema?